# Which tables in a Wordpress database need to be edited for migration to a new URL?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, database-migration

I have seen many questions related to database migration, but none which clearly state: When editing a database which of the tables do I actually need to edit?

As a force of habit I edit the entire mySQL database, and usually that works out. (However on occasion this can mess up URL left in user comments for instance.) However it would be good to know specifically which tables I actually need to edit in order to complete a migration correctly.

EDIT: I already understand how a migration works and which [tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to use, and I have read the codex entry on migration. I am not having a specific problem migrating.

This is really more of a best practices question.

What I am looking for is a definitive list of what tables I can exclude from my search and replace. For instance I know that the basic URL info is in wp_options, I know that (some) image paths are stored in wp_postmeta. Basically I want to exclude every table I possibly can, while still preserving the site's widgets, images, settings, etc.

Comment: Mainly wp_posts table. Refer: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: do you want to edit the siteurl ?

Comment: you can `use search & replace plugin` to search your old url's and replace it to new one in all the wp tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only references that HAVE to change are in the `wp_options` table. One is the `home` url and the other is the `siteurl`. These will allow you to log into the admin and view the frontend. However, you will still have to update your permalinks and rewrite rules using the admin.

I would still suggest an automated solution, however. I use [this tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to find and replace database references. It is specifically made for wordpress, but it will work for any database. It also will allow you to select which tables to update and will work with serialized strings so you should be able to avoid errors in the comments section.

Simply drop the file on the root of your wordpress install and run through the prompts. Make sure to deselect the `wp_comments` and `wp_commentmeta` tables. Also, make sure you remove the file on production as it presents a potential security threat.

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS**

Other than the two spots above, there are several places in the database that URLs are stored. Most plugins will store their options in the `wp_options` table. Typically, plugins will also serialize the data to avoid a ton of queries. You can't simply change the URL in the serialized data however, because there are length references in the serialized string. So if your current URL is 15 characters long and the new one is 20, you need to update the URL and the string length too. If you don't, PHP will just ignore the value. I believe this is a security measure to avoid code injection.

For assets in the media section the URLs are stored in the `wp_posts` under the post type `attachment`. If you are hardcoding absolute links in your posts, you may need to parse those as well (if this is the case, you can probably just parse the entire table). If you are using any sort of custom field plugin or doing anything with post meta for URLs you are also going to want to go through `wp_postmeta`.

One other thing to mention is that some plugins will add their own database tables. These are obviously on a per case basis, but a good rule of thumb is to try running a query for "%http%" in any string columns to see if there are hardcoded URLs. Here is the query I will use:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE '%http%'
```

Comment: I think just editing wp_options is a little too minimal. I am looking for a best practice that will update image paths, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Download the file from the following link http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/. 
Put it in the root folder and access the file and follow the steps and replace the urls.

I have been using it for quite a long time without any issues.

Hope it helps!

Thanks

Comment: Did you even read my post? or the other answers? This script has been mentioned twice already. Also it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I am sorry for repeating the link to the script.

but using this shouldn't disturb anything and should work and you are right about the affected tables to be options, and postmeta until unless you are using a plugin which needs replacement too.

So I feel the safest and the  best way is to use the above script :)

Comment: I reiterate this does not answer the question. Don't post if you don't have a possible solution.

Comment: I have come across another useful link where we dont have to search and replace at all when migrating from one server to another

http://drujoopress.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/how-to-use-single-wordpress-db-with-different-codebase/

Hope it helps :)